# Flutter BlocProvider can't be assigned to the parameter type

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use the blocks but I don't understand. When I want to group my navigation in a BlocRouter class I get an error message.
The error message is :

***"The argument type 'BlocProvider' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Route'."***

Here my files :

**MainScaffold :** In this file I have the error message

```
class MainScaffold extends StatelessWidget{
  final String title;
  MainScaffold({this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
      body : Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text("Choose a bloc"),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Counter"),
              onPressed : () => Navigator.of(context).push(BlocRouter().counterDetail()), // ERROR MESSAGE HERE
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**BlocRouter :**

```
class BlocRouter{
  MaterialPageRoute counterPage() => MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => counterDetail());
  BlocProvider counterDetail() => BlocProvider<CounterBloc>(bloc: CounterBloc(),child: CounterScreen());
}
```

**CounterBloc :**

```
class CounterBloc extends Bloc{

  int counter = 0;
  final _streamController = StreamController<int>();
  Sink<int> get sink =>_streamController.sink;
  Stream<int> get stream => _streamController.stream;

  CounterBloc(){
    sink.add(counter);
  }

  incrementCounter(){
    counter = counter + 1;
    sink.add(counter);
  }

  decrementCounter(){
    counter = counter - 1;
    sink.add(counter);
  }

  @override
  dispose(){
    return _streamController.close();
  }
}
```

**BlocProvider :**

```
class BlocProvider<T extends Bloc> extends StatefulWidget{
  final T bloc;
  final Widget child;
  BlocProvider({@required this.bloc, @required this.child});
  static T of<T extends Bloc>(BuildContext context){
    final BlocProvider<T> provider = context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<BlocProvider<T>>();
    return provider.bloc;
  }

  State createState() => _BlocProviderState();
}

class _BlocProviderState extends State<BlocProvider>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.bloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push` requires a `Route` and you're passing a `BlocProvider`. Pass a `MaterialPageRoute` in `push` and do the following:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BlocRouter().counterDetail()),
);
```